# Python Pandas regex match

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have some text like  **test text 1 (something xxx)**   in excel file. I am trying to match everything inside the bracket () including the brackets

Below Pandas code that i use is not matching any record.

`regex_pat = re.compile(r"\(.*$")`
`df['column'].str.match(regex_pat)`

But the same pattern `\(.*$`is working in notepad++ regex search. DO i need to change anything here.

Comment: Depending on your mode, `$` can match the end of the string of the end of the line. Which is your case? Can't you use simply `\([^()]*\)`?

Comment: If you just need what is inside `()` with nothing before or after, then this `\(([^)]+)\)` should be enough

Comment: Use `str.contains` since `str.match` only searches at the string start.